# Why do I have to deactivate and activate Propellerhead Balance in Device Manager to get audio?

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers

Every time I start my Windows 10 PC, the audio (Propellerhead Balance) is not working. I have two choices to get the audio back:

1. Restart the PC.
2. In device management; Deactivate and then activate Propellerhead Balance.

I have confirmed that I have the latest driver installed. The Propellerhead Balance has been discontinued, so there is no hope in a driver update.

The device has worked perfectly fine for several years, even on Windows 10. The problems started after I replaced my mainboard, and just kept the old Windows installation. Everything else on my system is working as normal.

I'm thinking that there may be some registry confusion at play here, causing the device to not register properly upon boot.

How can I fix this permanently, without having to reinstall Windows or buy a new audio device?

Comment: If it's in a USB3 port, then try plugging it into a USB 2.0 port. Some have said this as a solution.

Comment: My first thought is: since the mainboard is new, this is a BIOS/USB interaction issue. I don't know what board you have nor the settings available to it, but maybe look at "USB legacy support" and/or things like "USB 3.0 Mode". Try toggling these from e.g. auto to disabled etc. Perhaps also look at any settings that allow USB to charge when the system is off (S3 sleep state??).